bcc tools on Ubuntu 22.04
I follow this instruction to install bcc tools on Ubuntu 22.04 and this tutorial to run some examples of eBPF. However when I try to access /usr/share/bcc/tools,
sudo apt install bpfcc-tools


 ls /usr/share/bcc/tools

I 've got an error
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/bcc/tools': No such file or directory

How to install bcc tools scripts properly?

Just pointing to an instruction (with many sections) doesn't really give any clue. Please in your question post the commands you used to install it, including any output. Thanks.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
